# Simple filter to unhardwrap multiple paragraphs

Tags: command-line, clipboard, markdown

I have many markdown files which are hardwrapped to 80 characters. I would like to copy these to paste into textareas (`xclip -sel clipboard < file`), but want them to wordwrap normally. This is simple w/o paragraphs - `tr "\n" " " < file | xclip -sel clipboard`, but turns all text into a run-on paragraph which still requires manual copy-editing.

Is there a short and simple filter using standard *NIX tools (GNU versions are fine) to delete all "\n" *except* when there are two next to each other? Ideally something I can remember and retype - less than 30 characters with no files. It feels like something `sed` should be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `perl`:

For example, using the following hard-wrapped example input file:

```
$ cat input.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

```
$ perl -0777 -p -e 's/(?<!\n)\n/ /g' input.txt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Or if you still want a blank line between each paragraph:

```
$ perl -0777 -p -e 's/(?<!\n)\n/ /g; s/\n/\n\n/g' input.txt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Note: unless the input ends in one or more blank lines, the output won't have a newline on the last line.  If you need that, add `; END {print "\n"}` to the end of the script. This will guarantee that the output will end with a newline.

The `-0777` option tells perl to "slurp" in its input file all at once, and process it as one long string.

Both versions of the one-liner above use a feature of perl regular expressions called a "zero-width negative lookbehind assertion" - `(?<!pattern)`.  See `man perlre` and search for "Lookaround Assertions" for details.  In short, `(?<!\n)\n` matches a newline **unless** the character before it is another newline - and it does this without actually matching or capturing the preceding character (that's what the "zero-width assertion" means).

Without using negative look behind assertion, you might be tempted to do something like `s/[^\n]\n/ /g` - but that would end up deleting every character immediately before each newline....which is why the zero-width part of the regex is important, it prevents that.  Another alternative is to use something like `s/([^\n])\n/\1 /g` which captures the character before the newline and uses it in the replacement - e.g. with GNU sed: `sed -E -z 's/([^\n])\n/\1 /g' input.txt` but IMO it's better to not match the preceding character at all than to match & delete it and then put it back.

Some other regex engines also support look-around assertions, but they're non-standard so not guaranteed to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

`tr "\n" " " < file | sed 's/  /\n/g;s/ $//'` might work adequately. It requires single-spaced sentences (which some people hate) to re-add the paragraph newlines. It also trims the added space from the final line of the file.